# React Hook (usestate ) not working when combined with socket io

Tags: javascript, socket.io, components, hook, use-state

I'm going crazy. I really don't understand why the below is not working. I'm starting with react.
I'm trying to fetch **datas** from server and load my state before rendering.
Socket "fromAPI" is ok, this is only a timer.
Socket "lobbyUpdate " not working , i'm fetching data from database.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:2500";

function Lobby() {

    const [response, setResponse] = useState("")
    const [updates, setUpdates] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);

        socket.on("FromAPI", data => {
          setResponse(data);
        });

        socket.on('lobbyUpdate', datas => {
           console.log(updates) // Nothing 
           setUpdates(datas)

           console.log(datas) // datas are displayed
           console.log(updates) // nothing is displayed
          
        })
       
        // CLEAN UP THE EFFECT
        return () => socket.disconnect();
        //
      }, []);
```

[console-capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYcQm.png)

Please can you help me ? i didn't find similar case .
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `updates` inside the `useEffect` is referencing the value from the *initial render*, rather than the value currently being rendered. To fix it, either use refs instead of (or in addition to) state, or have the `useEffect` run every time the updates change:

```
function Lobby() {
    const [response, setResponse] = useState("")
    const [updates, setUpdates] = useState([])
    const socketRef = useRef();
    // Create the socket
    // and add the API listener:
    useEffect(() => {
        socketRef.current = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
        socketRef.current.on("FromAPI", setResponse);
        return () => socketRef.current.disconnect();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleLobbyUpdate =  (datas) => {
            console.log(updates); // this will now display the current data
            setUpdates(datas);
        };
        socketRef.current.on('lobbyUpdate', handleLobbyUpdate);
        return () => {
            socketRef.current.off('lobbyUpdate', handleLobbyUpdate);
        }
    }, [updates]);
```

Remember that state setters are asynchronous, so you won't see a change in the `updates` variable immediately after calling `setUpdates` - you'll have to wait until the next render for the `updates` to become populated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine, you just have your log statements in places where they aren't useful.

`updates` is a local const. It will never change, and that's not what `setUpdates` is trying to do. The console.log statements in the useEffect will only ever be referring to the values that `response` and `updates` had at the time of the first render.

When you call `setUpdates`, you are asking react to rerender the component. On that new render, a new local const will be created, and it will get the new value. Code in the new render can use this value, but code in the previous render can not. If you want to verify that it is rerendering with the new value, then put your log statement into the body of the component:

```
function Lobby() {

    const [response, setResponse] = useState("")
    const [updates, setUpdates] = useState([])

    console.log("rendering with: ", response, updates);

    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);

        socket.on("FromAPI", data => {
          setResponse(data);
        });

        socket.on('lobbyUpdate', datas => {
           setUpdates(datas)
        })
       
        // CLEAN UP THE EFFECT
        return () => socket.disconnect();
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must define your socket const inside the useEffect()
it will render the useEffect hook after every socket update.

```
const [update,setupdate] = useState()

useEffect(()=>{ 
const socket = io("http://localhost:3001");
socket.on("send data", function (data_from_socket) {
 setupdate(data_from_socket);
})
})
```

and dont forget to not to use [] in useEfect